# JUnit 4 base functionality

Tags: unit-testing, junit4

What is the proper way with JUnit 4 to create test cases to use common functionality: e.g. setup that is common to several unit test classes?  What I did was create a test case and put the common functionality in the `@Before` method, then any test case that needs this would extend the base class.  However, this seems to require doing: `super.setUp()` in every subclass.

Is there a better way?

**EDIT**

Actually my proposed solution is not working.  Sometimes JUnit will call the base class TWICE.  Once if it happens to run the test on the base class first, and again when it reaches a child class (at least I think this is whats happening).  So a better way of "inheriting" common test case functionality would be great.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to invoker `super.setup()` if you use the [`@Before` annotation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html):

> When writing tests, it is common to find that several tests need
>   similar objects created before they
>   can run. Annotating a public void
>   method with `@Before` causes that method
>   to be run before the Test method. The
>   `@Before` methods of superclasses will
>   be run before those of the current
>   class.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
  @Before
  public void initForAll() {}
```

In the super/Main class

and any

```
  @Before
  public void initTest() {...}
```

In your Testcases.

*EDIT:*

To answer your questions in the edit.

1. You could use `@BeforeClass` which will be invoked once per TestClass.
2. But I Think you are looking for something like a lazy /static Initialisation.

I do this like this:

```
private boolean initialized = false;

@BeforeClass
public static void init()
{
  if(initialized)
  {
    return;
  }

  //Initialize everything

  initialized = true;
}
```

Comment: if both the annotated @before methods have the same name, the subclass will override the one in the superclass, thus requiring me to call super.setUp, I think.

Comment: I'd suggest that you give the super one a special name, that you will not reuse. The name of the annotated method is irrelevant. Just choose different names.

Comment: Why wasn't this answer accepted. It solves the problem in the post?

Answer (score 0):

thats a pretty good way to do it.  If you have a `setUp()` on the subclass, then yes, you have to invoke `super.setUp()`, but really, how hard is that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other approach.
Instead of creating a base class with a common functionality, make an util class with static methods which will the common functionality. Then just call util methods in @Before annotated method of each test case.

Answer (score 0):

If your base class has a method public void setUp(), and so does your sub-class, then the sub-class's setUp method **overrides** the base class's method of the same name and signature, so only the sub-class's method will be called (and it may be called when the base class's method should have been called; not sure about this).

The solution is to call your base class setup method something else, e.g. baseSetup().  Then they will both be called automatically.  Joachim's answer does address the naming, but I wanted to be clearer about the effects of method override.